# HTTP response status for missing if-match header

Tags: rest, http

I have a REST-ful service which is using ETags and If-Match headers to control updates.

If a client submits a conditional request with an If-Match header, and the ETag is stale, I am returning a 412 Precondition Failed, which appears to be the recommended approach to an ETag mismatch.

But what if the client submits without an If-* header?  My understanding of 412 is that it applies to Client preconditions.  Since the client did not submit an If-Match header, there are no client preconditions.  But if I want to require If-Match, what response should I use?

My thinking so far is maybe 400 Bad Request or 409 Conflict.  Are there any best practices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the code `400` is a bit general but can apply. In such case, you need to provide more details about the problem within the response content.

IMO, code `409` should be used if there is a conflict with the current state of the resource. I think that it's more in the case where you implement optimitic locking by yourself without using headers `ETag` and `If-*`.

I saw a code `428` (Precondition Required) that seems to correspond to your needs.

The following page could give you more details: http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: 428 is the correct code. The right place to look things up though is http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml